# Join Non ContentPart Table to ContentPart Table Using Orchard HQL API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hql, orchardcms

I am trying to perform a simple join between two different tables using the Orchard HQL API. The problem is that one of the tables is not a ContentPartTable. Is this possible??

Here is what it would look like in regular SQL:

```
Select * From ItemPartRecord 
Join ItemRecord
On ItemRecord.ItemId = ItemPartRecord.ItemId
Where ItemRecord.Price Between 1000 and 10000
```

How exactly could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how to do this:

```
 //Join the non content part table
var defaultHqlQuery = query as DefaultHqlQuery;
var fiJoins = typeof(DefaultHqlQuery).GetField("_joins", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var joins = fiJoins.GetValue(defaultHqlQuery) as List<Tuple<IAlias, Join>>;
joins.Add(new Tuple<IAlias, Join>(new Alias("ExampleNamespace.Data.Models"), new Join("ExampleRecord", "ExampleAlias", ",")));
Action<IHqlExpressionFactory> joinOn = predicate => predicate.EqProperty("valueToJoinOn", "aliasToJoinOn.valueToJoinOn");
query = query.Where(
alias => alias.Named("ExampleAlias"),
joinOn
);
```

Comment: You're using reflection to get access to a Private field "_joins" which is actually a bad practice, no? The field is private for a reason.

Comment: This is true, the orchard HQL API is generally difficult to use, it only exposes aspects that are specific to orchard content part records as appose to actually sql tables which is why I believe I did this..