# Custom sort Criterion HQL query for a custom part with no ContentPartRecord

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am trying to create a custom sort criterion for projection module to sort any content based on Ratings or number of favorites. I have attached StarsPart from Orchard.Module.Contrib.Stars Module and FavoritePart from Orchard.Module.NGM.Favorite module to my content. But These modules are based on contrib.Voting module and these parts do not have corresponding ContentPartRecord.

my problem is how do I write the HQL query to sort the content, if I write query as following then i get exception that "Unable to cast object of type `Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultAliasFactory` to type `StarsPart`."

```
 if (context.State.SortBy != null)
        {
            var _SortBy = _tokenizer.Replace(context.State.SortBy, null, new ReplaceOptions { Encoding = ReplaceOptions.NoEncode });
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SortBy))
            {
                switch ((string)_SortBy)
                {
                    case "HighestRated":
                        context.Query.OrderBy(
                            alias => alias.ContentItem().As<StarsPart>(), x => x.Asc("UserRating"));
                        break;
                    case "MostFavorited":
                        context.Query.OrderBy(
                            alias => alias.ContentItem().As<FavoritePart>(), x => x.Asc("NumberOfFavorites"));
                        break;
                    default:
                         context.Query.OrderBy(
                            alias => alias.ContentItem().As<UserViewPart>(), x => x.Asc("TotalViews"));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any other way to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out the answer myself finally with the help of this [question]:[Join Non ContentPart Table to ContentPart Table Using Orchard HQL API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321375/join-non-contentpart-table-to-contentpart-table-using-orchard-hql-api).

Here is the final code for ApplyFilter method.

---

```
 public void ApplyFilter(SortCriterionContext context)
    {

        bool ascending = false;
        if (context.State.SortAsc != null)
        {
            var _SortAsc = _tokenizer.Replace(
                context.State.SortAsc, null, new ReplaceOptions { Encoding = ReplaceOptions.NoEncode });
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SortAsc)) ascending = Convert.ToBoolean(_SortAsc);
        }

        System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (context.State.SortBy != null)
        {
            var _SortBy = _tokenizer.Replace(
                context.State.SortBy, null, new ReplaceOptions { Encoding = ReplaceOptions.NoEncode });
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SortBy))
            {

                switch ((string)_SortBy)
                {
                    case "HR": //Highest Rated
                        dictionary.Add("Dimension", Dimensions.Rating.ToString());
                        dictionary.Add("FunctionName", "average");
                        break;
                    case "MF": //Most favorited
                        dictionary.Add("Dimension", Dimensions.Favorite.ToString());
                        dictionary.Add("FunctionName", "sum");
                        break;
                    case "MV":
                        //"Most viewed"
                        dictionary.Add("Dimension", Dimensions.ContentViews.ToString());
                        dictionary.Add("FunctionName", "sum");
                        break;
                        //ToDo: Need to work on recently published
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (dictionary.Keys.Count == 0)
        {
            //This is to handle default case. highest rating
            dictionary.Add("Dimension", Dimensions.Rating.ToString());
            dictionary.Add("FunctionName", "average");
        }
        {
            var query = (IHqlQuery)context.Query;
            query.Join(alias => alias.ContentItem());
            var defaultHqlQuery = query as DefaultHqlQuery;
            var fiJoins = typeof(DefaultHqlQuery).GetField("_joins", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var joins = fiJoins.GetValue(defaultHqlQuery) as List<System.Tuple<IAlias, Join>>;
            joins.Add(
                new System.Tuple<IAlias, Join>(
                    new Alias("Contrib.Voting.Models"), new Join("ResultRecord", "result", ",")));

            context.Query = query.Where(
                alias => alias.Named("result"), predicate => predicate.EqProperty("ContentItemRecord", "ci"));
            context.Query = context.Query.Where(
                alias => alias.Named("result"), predicate => predicate.AllEq(dictionary));
            Action<IHqlSortFactory> sortOrderAction = x => x.Desc("Value");

            if (ascending) sortOrderAction = x => x.Asc("Value");

            context.Query = context.Query.OrderBy(alias => alias.Named("result"), sortOrderAction);
        }

    }
```

Comment: While this answer works but the query selects only the content items which have votes. But i need to select all the content even if they do not have ratings/favorites. Based on votes i only want to sort the content. Is it possible to convert the query in left outer join?